# AWS: Amazon Personalize and Amazon S3: "InvalidInputException: Insufficient privileges for accessing data in S3"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-personalize

I am receiving the following error when trying to run some code in Amazon SageMaker:

> InvalidInputException: An error occurred (InvalidInputException) when calling the CreateDatasetImportJob operation: Insufficient privileges for accessing data in S3. Please look at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/personalize/latest/dg/granting-personalize-s3-access.html and ensure your role is configured correctly.

The code I am trying to run is as follows:

```py
create_interactions_dataset_import_job_response = personalize.create_dataset_import_job(
    jobName = 'interactions-import-job-v1',
    datasetArn = interactions_dataset_arn,
    dataSource = {'dataLocation' : 's3://{}/{}'.format(bucket_name, interactions_filename)},
    roleArn = role_arn)

dataset_import_job_interactions_arn=create_interactions_dataset_import_job_response['datasetImportJobArn']
```

I have attached FullAccess policies for S3, Personalize, and SageMaker to my role, as well as a customer-managed policy PersonalizeS3BucketAccessPolicy (as suggested by the documentation):

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "PersonalizeS3BucketAccessPolicy",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PersonalizeS3BucketAccessPolicy",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Similarly, in the S3 bucket I want to access, I attached the following policy:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "PersonalizeS3BucketAccessPolicy",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PersonalizeS3BucketAccessPolicy",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "personalize.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I've also tried attaching this policy to the s3 bucket:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "personalize.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "personalize.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "personalize.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "bucket_name/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I've tried messing around with the policies and permissions, but nothing has worked so I've reverted to the above code. At this point I've been staring at all of this so long that I don't know if my problem is with my code, my permissions, or the policies I put above. Any help trying to identify the problem is greatly appreciated.

Edit 11/14:

Other things I have tried:

*In the PersonalizeS3BucketAccessPolicy:*

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [       
      {
          
        "Effect": "Allow",           
        "Action": [               
          "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",               
          "s3:DeleteObject",               
          "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",               
          "s3:PutObject"           
        ],           
        "Resource": [               
          "arn:aws:s3:::your_s3_bucket/*"           
        ]       
      },       
      {           
        "Effect": "Allow",           
        "Action": [               
          "s3:GetBucketLocation",               
          "s3:ListBucket",               
          "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads"           
        ],           
        "Resource": [               
          "arn:aws:s3:::your_s3_bucket"           
      ]       
    }
  ]
}
```

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListStorageLensConfigurations",
                "s3:ListAccessPointsForObjectLambda",
                "s3:GetAccessPoint",
                "s3:PutAccountPublicAccessBlock",
                "s3:GetAccountPublicAccessBlock",
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:ListAccessPoints",
                "s3:PutAccessPointPublicAccessBlock",
                "s3:ListJobs",
                "s3:PutStorageLensConfiguration",
                "s3:ListMultiRegionAccessPoints",
                "s3:CreateJob"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::*",
                "arn:aws:s3:*:123456789999:job/*",
                "arn:aws:s3::123456789999:accesspoint/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:*:123456789999:storage-lens/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:*:123456789999:accesspoint/*",
                "arn:aws:s3-object-lambda:*:123456789999:accesspoint/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:us-west-2:123456789999:async-request/mrap/*/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::*/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::*",
                "arn:aws:s3:*:123456789999:job/*",
                "arn:aws:s3::123456789999:accesspoint/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::*/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:*:123456789999:storage-lens/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:*:123456789999:accesspoint/*",
                "arn:aws:s3-object-lambda:*:123456789999:accesspoint/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:us-west-2:123456789999:async-request/mrap/*/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

*In the bucket policy itself:*

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Statement1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "personalize.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name"
        }
    ]
}
```

The files in my bucket are not encrypted. I'm still not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are the file(s) in your bucket that you're trying import encrypted? Note item #4 on this documentation page. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/personalize/latest/dg/granting-personalize-s3-access.html

Comment: The files in my bucket are not encrypted.